# Certain Penny Graphs Requiring 4 Colors For Proper Vertex Coloring?

Tags: graph-theory

Wikipedia showcases a penny graph that requires 4 colors for a proper coloring on the vertices. Why does this graph require 4 colors instead of 3?

[image: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/fc/Penny_graph_11_nodes.svg/300px-Penny_graph_11_nodes.svg.png]

More Generally I'm looking for a general condition in a penny graph $G$ that results in $\chi(G)=4$.

I've been told that looking at the vertices farthest from each other should help, but I don't know what about them to consider. In wikipedia's example, all I see is that these vertices each have degree 3, and their vertex induced subgraphs will have coloring in 3 colors. Then I guess you could argue that the rest of the vertices have uniquely defined colors that lead to a necessary 4th color, but how would I formalize and/or generalize this?

Comment: In each diamond shape (ie $K_4$ minus an edge), the two opposite vertices have the same colour in any 3-colouring. So if the top middle vertex is black, then so is the rightmost vertex, and the leftmost vertex, and....

Comment: much shorter than my proof. I like it. I did out 6 cases permuting the coloring of one of the vertex induced subgraphs (diamonds) of the 2 farthest apart vertices in the graph. Found the same result. What about generalizing the result though?